# How should i store an image with related info (notes, date)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

So right now I'm storing images like so:

```
NSData * data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
NSArray *directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [directories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *key = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"screenshots.archive"];
NSMutableArray *storageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:key];
if(!storageArray){
    storageArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:data];
}
else{
    [storageArray addObject:data];
}
[storageArray writeToFile:key atomically:YES];
```

And retrieving them like this in my UITableViewController subclass:

```
imgArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath]]
```

To my question. I want a String(notes) and a Date to "accompany" the sceenshots, and I'm not sure how to do this correctly. I'm thinking of creating a "screenshot" class which contains the image, String and Date, and persist these objects with Core Data. But i see some people recommend not doing this due to performance issues when storing images in a DB.

But how would you approach this?

Comment: Forgot to add that in the tableViewController the images might switch positions, which is one of the things that makes this hard to manage (for me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I would most definitely recommend you to create a class to wrap all those info altogether.

You would then be able to implement your own version of `writeToFile:` and `initWithContentFile:` Your code will gain in flexibility.

About coreData, the problem is not storing image in the DB, it is storing them in a bad way.
The common mistake would be to create a Table with a date field, a string field and a blob field for the imageData. This would be poor design because when you'll want to retrieve all your record, core data will have to load in memory as well all your images whether your user is planning to see them or not! That would be a huge waste of memory, time and well, performance in general.

The good design is to have 2 tables:

- One image table with a string and date fields
- and one imageDataTable with just the blob

The 2 table are then linked by a one-to-one relationship. Now when you fetch all your images, you load only the title, the date and the id of the pict instead of the whole pic itself! Much more efficient, and you can go and fetch the pic anytime if the user wants to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Store the date and the notes string and the NAME of the image in Core Data. Continue to store the image on the file system and load it from there when needed.